# How to do this vlookup in excel?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have one Excel document with two sheets Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1 data is as below.

```
    sno        absolute name      new field
    ---        -------------      ---------
    1           abc
    2           defgh
    3           rose
```

Sheet2 data is as below.

```
 absolute name      new field
 -------------      ---------
 abc                apple 
 defgh              mango
 rose               orange
```

The output should end up in Sheet1 as:

```
sno        absolute name      new field
---        -------------      ---------
1           abc                apple
2           defgh              mango
3           rose               orange
```

consider the above data as sample data.

How do you do the vlookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your answer:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:B, 2)
```

Comment: Hi Lance thank you very much for answering I too did in the same way

Comment: =VLOOKUP(K6,pset_total_info,2,FALSE) where pset_total_info is the total range in the sheet2 document.

Comment: @srihari, good, that's what I got to work, so you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Yeh I have more doubt if that can be answered here for the values that are not found I am getting #N/A  so how can I make those cells to blank empty values?

Comment: @srihari, well you need to say that then in your question.  You need to give all the details.  I at first got N/A also, and found I'd just made a small mistake, so go over all of the basics, you'll probably find it in there someplace.  Or make a questions will all details needed so someone can figure it out.

Comment: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(K6,pset_total_info,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(K6,pset_total_info,2,FALSE)) is the way we can eliminate #N/A with blanks.

Comment: Oh, I see I think, you're getting N/A maybe because you have no matching value.  In that case, what you're doing with ISNA is probably a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

This formula help you:-

=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:B, 2,0)